# property without retain with example

Tags: objective-c, properties, retain

if we use a property without the "retain", what does it change? i have this example :

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;  
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;
```

in the .m :

```
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord{  
    coordinate = coord;  
    return self;  
}
```

the "retain"  is normally used for the setter, isn't it? so here, we use the setter, in initWith..., but we don't use "retain"... any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CLLocationCoordinate2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010238-CH2-SW15) is not an Objective C object, so attempting to send `retain` and `release` to it doesn't make sense.

```
 @property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

This declares an assign read only property, which is the only correct thing to do for a property with a plain C type.  Additionally you have said it is `nonatomic` which means that there is no code to synchronize the property.  Since the property is a struct consisting of two 64 bit values, that probably means that you can get an inconsistent result back if you read the property at the same time as some other thread is changing it.

> the "retain" is normally used for the setter, isn't it? so here, we use the setter, in initWith...

No, you don't actually.  The line

```
coordinate = coord;
```

actually assigns the instance variable directly.  However, this is what you want in this case.  If the property was not read/write and was an Objective-C object type, it would still be assigning the instance variable directly.  In that case, you'd need one of the following.

```
[self setCoordinate: coord];
```

or

```
self.coordinate = coord;
```

or

```
coordinate = [coord retain]; // in init only
```

---

By the way, your `init` is wrong.  It should follow the pattern:

```
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord{ 
    self = [super init]; // assuming init is the designated initialiser of the super class
    if (self != nil)
    { 
        coordinate = coord;
    }
    return self;  
}
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer, i'm not sure to understand the nonatomic thing, what does it mean to "synchronize the property"? i read through the doc but i'm not sure about the meaning of that. For the explanation, thanks a lot

Comment: @Paul:  Basically, it means that reads and writes are surrounded by locks to prevent the two from happening simultaneously in a threaded environment.

Answer (score 2):

In your specific case, `readonly` means that you class allocates the object and then gives access to it through a property that does not allow this property to be changed from outside.

In general, the object will be nevertheless retained by the class when it allocates it, and released when dealloc is executed.
In your case, the object of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is copied when assigning to the ivar:

```
 coordinate = coord;
```

because it is not a pointer object, rather a simple struct made out of 2 doubles:

```
 typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
 typedef struct {
     CLLocationDegrees latitude;
     CLLocationDegrees longitude;
 } CLLocationCoordinate2D;
```

So, that is the reason why you don't see any retain in the code. If instead of being a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object, it had been an `NSString` you would have probably needed a retain when doing the assignment to the ivar. (I say "probably" because it all depends on the ownership of the assigned object).

Answer (score 1):

The `retain` property is used for *objects* that need to be (surprise) retained. That is: your objects needs the object assigned to the property to stay around, it may not be deallocated.

In your case, it wouldn't change anything as a struct, not an object.

But what you're using in the cited code is `readonly`, and that means *there is no setter, only a getter.*